# receive() method of receiving mail resulting in 405 Method Not Allowed

Tags: python, google-app-engine, email

In my app whenever  I am trying to receive email of my app and sending request to receive() method then I am getting error **405 Method Not Allowed**.

sending an email is working fine through the id string@appid.appspotmail.com, but receiving email to this id results into this error.

I configured my app like this

## app.yaml

```
application: abc
version: 1
runtime: python27
api_version: 1
threadsafe : false

inbound_services:
- mail 

handlers:  
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: incoming_mail.py
  login: admin

- url: /
  script: abc.py
```

## incoming_mail.py

```
import email
import logging
from google.appengine.ext import webapp
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):

    def receive(self,email):
        logging.info("Received a message from: %s" %   email.sender)


app = webapp.WSGIApplication([LogSenderHandler.mapping()], debug=True)

def main():
    run_wsgi_app(app)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

whenever I am going through this url http://appid.appspot.com/_ah/mail/string@appid.appspotmail.com

I am getting error **405 Method not allowed**.

Completely stuck. Thanks in advance for any help you can offer!

Answer (score 0):

The GAE doesn't store your incoming mail. You need to store it and create your own code to manage it. They mention "/_ah/mail/address" to explain how to handle it in the app.yaml. If you scroll down you can see how to handle multiple different handlers.

You get a "405 Method not allowed The method GET is not allowed for this resource. " because you have no ***Get*** handler in your code.

Personally I would store the email in a Ancestor-Key Datastore (Parent being who it was sent to) and have another script handle managing it (ie view, reply, delete).

Comment: thanks for your reply. If gae doesn’t store the mail then how can I trace all the mail received to the app? Cause I am getting error to trace the mail,  receive method resulting error then how I would be able to get all the email of the app. 

PS I have a get method in another handler and which I route through app.yaml on additional patterns.

Comment: When the receive(self,email) is called store the mail into the Datastore. Then you'll need to create another page to view it.